# Sum column in HTML table, Javascript based on name + row count

Tags: javascript, html

First time posting here so apologies if this isn't quite right.

I have a table that a user fills out as a timesheet - the user can do 1 or 100 jobs per week so the table has an addrow function to add a new row depending on amount of jobs done.
I'm thinking of keeping the name of each input unique to make it easier to post and process later.
So my table has columns: project number, date, hours on site, project details.
the input names go up in 1's for each row added e.g. Project 1 - input name"hours1"...Project 2 - input name"hours2" etc.

I want to be able to add these hours up and give a weeks total for amount of hours worked.
I can get it to work if all my hour inputs are named "hours" but i'd like to keep them seperately named for processing later.
Code Below
Many thanks in advance.

My Timesheet Table HTML code

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped" id="timesheet_table">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th width="10%">
                                <h4>Project #</h4>
                                </th>
                                <th width="15%">
                                    <h4>Date</h4>
                                </th>
                                <th width="15%">
                                    <h4>Hours</h4>
                                </th>
                                <th width="60%">
                                    <h4>Location / Details</h4>
                                </th>
                                <th width="0%">
                                    <h4></h4>
                                </th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <p class="card-text">1</p>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="form-group form-group-sm no-margin-bottom">
                                        <input id="projects" type="date" name="pd" >
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="form-group form-group-sm no-margin-bottom">
                                        <input id="projects" type="number" name="hours" step=".25" >
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="form-group form-group-sm no-margin-bottom">
                                        <input id="projects" type="text" name="project" >
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                <label>Total <input type="text" required="required" class="small" name="total"></label>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success mr-1 mb-1" onclick="addRows();"><i class="la la-plus"></i></button>
```

My AddRow Function

```
<script>  
    function addRows () {
    var table = document.getElementById('timesheet_table');
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    var iteration = rowCount -1;
    var numbers = iteration +1;
    var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
    var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;

    // Cell for number
    var cell = row.insertCell(0);
    var label = document.createElement('label');
    label.textContent = numbers;
    cell.appendChild(label);

    for(var i=1; i<colCount; i++) {

        var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
        newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[1].cells[i].innerHTML;
        //alert(table.rows[1].cells[i].innerHTML);   .replace(/name="(.+)1"/, 'name="$1' + rowCount + '"');
        //alert(newcell.childNodes);

    }
}
    </script>
```

My Add Hours Function

```
    <script>
    const makeNum = str => isNaN(str) || str.trim() === "" ? 0 : +str;
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  const table = document.getElementById("timesheet_table");
  const tbody = table.querySelector("tbody");
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    var rownumber = rowCount -1;
  const grandTotal = document.querySelector("[name=sum]");
  tbody.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
    var sum = 0;
    [...tbody.querySelectorAll("tr")].forEach(row => {
      var hrs = makeNum(row.querySelector("[name=hours]").value);
      var total = hrs 
      sum += total;
      row.querySelector("[name=total]").value = total.toFixed(2);
    })
    grandTotal.value = sum.toFixed(2);
  })
})
    </script>
```

I have tried and failed with ("[name=hours" + rownumber + "]") and ("[name=total" + rownumber + "]"), I am very new to javascript and postings here so again sorry if this post isn't quite right or confusing.

When I add .replace(/name="(.+)1"/, 'name="$1' + rowCount + '"'); to newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[1].cells[i].innerHTML the add row function is prefect - giving me pd1,pd2,pd3 - hours1,hours2,hours3 etc for each new row.

with the current ("[name=hours" + rownumber + "]") it works on line 1 only - as soon as I add a new row the code stops functioning.

It's the javascript addition function i'm struggling with - how would i loop through the values of hours per row and add these up ?
would i use something similar to ("[name=hours" + rownumber + "]") or is that part of my script way off, or do i loop in a different way ?

All I want to do is add every 'hours' input up and give a total, but the number of rows can be infinite - Many Thanks for your help

Comment: _"I'm thinking of keeping the name of each input unique to make it easier to post and process later."_ - that is the opposite of making things easier. You will have to "generate" indexes out of a prefix and a counter variable on the receiving end then. Instead, use the "square bracket syntax" for your field names - `name="foo[]"`. Then PHP will provide you an _array_ in `$_GET['foo']` or `$_POST['foo']` respectively, that you can easily loop over.

Comment: Many thanks - I didn't know this was possible - after some research and playing around it works so well - Thank you so much for your answer !!